# Book about a young woman at expensive hotel who goes into the “grey” and sees dead people

Tags: story-identification, books, detective

In this book, a rich young woman, recovering from some trauma, is staying at an expensive hotel/resort. She can go into “grey” in certain areas of the hotel grounds and see dead people. I think a cop is helping her out. I believe there were murders at the hotel.

I read this book around 2010.  It was stand-alone and not part of a series.

Comment: Can you go through [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and add some details?

Answer (score 9):

### This sounds like the [Greywalker](http://katrichardson.com/?page_id=7) series by Kat Richardson.

The protagonist of the series, Harper Blaine, is a PI who gained the ability to see ghosts and other supernatural creatures after spending two minutes dead and then being revived.

The supernatural world is referred to as 'The Grey' (hence the title of the series and first book).  Near-death (or temporary death) experiences are one of the ways people ever this world.

I couldn't find any references to rich women entering the Grey in any of the story synopses  (I have only read the first book), but it could easily be a lesser detail, or from a short story (which would fit with Harper, presumably the 'cop' you remember, being a secondary character), and everything else lines up perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I will look into this series on Amazon.

Comment: My research indicates that you might have read the short story "[The Third Death of the Little Clay Dog](https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/132897/6/Mean_Streets.html)", @CarolHallSloinne, published as a short story in the anthology *Mean Streets* in 2009. It involves the will of a rich woman and a few scenes that take place in locations that could easily be misremembered as hotels. (Based off of this answer, I searched the author's website for short stories, looked at the "Anthologies" page, saw "Mean Streets", went to Wikipedia, and searched for an online version of the story to verify.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  She was definitely staying a a resort or upscale hotel through the entire book.  Thanks again, Carol.